# Errors in configuring feature gate in gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying to run `kubelet parameters add --feature-gates=ReadOnlyAPIDataVolumes=false` on my GKE node with node version 1.9.7.

Then I got the following error:

```
I1002 00:56:53.617596   13469 feature_gate.go:226] feature gates: &{{} map[ReadOnlyAPIDataVolumes:false]}
I1002 00:56:53.617724   13469 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
I1002 00:56:53.617729   13469 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flags
error: error reading /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key, certificate and key must be supplied as a pair
```

If I run `sudo kubelet parameters add --feature-gates=ReadOnlyAPIDataVolumes=false`, then I got

```
error: unrecognized key: ReadOnlyAPIDataVolumes
```

My questions:

- In general, should kubelet command be executed from as root or not?
- Specifically how to run "kubelet parameters add" command successfully?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Although it may be possible to run as `non-root`, the kubelet has control over so many different components on your system that would be difficult to make it talk to all the components as `non-root`.
2. I'm really not sure where `kubelet parameters add` comes from, or how it's setup on GKE (I believe it's the good old `kube-up.sh` script) But generally, you can change your kubelet parameters at the `systemd` level. For example, I use kubeadm and change/add flags in `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` or just inline on the kubelet command line, according to this `systemd` service definition:

   ```
   $ systemctl cat kubelet
   # /lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service
   [Unit]
   Description=kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Documentation=https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet
   Restart=always
   StartLimitInterval=0
   RestartSec=10

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target

   # /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
   # Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
   [Service]
   Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap- kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --hostname-override=ip-x-x-x-x.us-east-1.compute.internal"
   Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
   # This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
   EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
   # This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
   # the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
   EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
   ```